# Textfields have no color when saved as svg in tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, svg, tensorboard

After manually downgrading my python version from 3.10 back to 3.9 and reinstalling most packages, I noticed that tensorboard isn't working as expected. The SVG saved contains the text fields of a graph, but they are not filled (worked out the problem in Inkscape. Do I have a package missing? I don't have any errors on the command line.

The image shows how an exported image looks like. I can see, that the text fields are there when marking them in Firefox.
[image: Image of tensorboard exported svg file]

Edit: I found the problem analyzing the pdf_tex files created from Inkscape. Apparently, the textcolor is set to {1,1,1} instead of {0,0,0} making them white. This issue comes from **using dark mode**.  If you use light mode, the text exported will be correct.

If you use normally dark mode on firefox, you need to switch manually to light mode on tensorboard to get the correct image.